# Real time robot position visualization

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ros node which simulates an underwater vehicle 2D motion, by reading the yaw reference angle from a topic published by another node and whose value is computed comparing the current vehicle position with respect to a desired one.

I would like to visualize the real time position of the vehicle (meaning while the node encharged to simulate the vehicle computes it) on a graph whose axes are the x and the y of the reference frame.

So far I have used rqt_plot, but it merely allows to visualize the topic contents referred to the time the data is computed.

Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275481/real-time-robot-position-visualization/) by [Nicola P](https://answers.ros.org/users/32558/nicola-p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz + https://github.com/ajshort/rviz_ortho_view_controller and broadcasting the position as a tf (or a Marker) is somewhat overkill but you are probably going to be using rviz anyhow.

Drawing onto an Image using opencv and publishing it or even using imshow is quick and dirty.  (I thought there was a turtlebot example that did this but I can't find it)

https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/2D_Plot_Tool hasn't been updated recently, there might be others.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1